# Java keeps returning exception - TextIO doesn't read from the file

Tags: java, filepath, readfile

I wrote the below code but nothing is coming up. I have the .txt file in the icecreamcones package but when I run the code, the exception is returned and nothing happens.

I changed the original .dat file to .txt. I tried moving it to /src and changing the path (which I might have done incorrectly but still didn't work either way).

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package icecreamcones;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class icecreamCones {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int totalCones = 0;
    int totalStrawberry = 0;
    String readFile;

        try {
              TextIO.readFile("icecream.txt");
           }

           catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
              System.out.println("File not found!");
           }


    while(!TextIO.eof()){
            readFile = TextIO.getln();
            totalCones++;
        if (readFile.equals("Strawberry")){
            totalStrawberry++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of sold cones is: " + totalCones);
         System.out.println("The total number of sold Strawberry flavoured cones is: " 
         + totalStrawberry);
    }
}


----------


I need to be able to print out the two statements so I need help figuring out how to make TextIO.readFile work.
```

Comment: *"I have the .txt file in the icecreamcones package"* then you can't read it as a "file", it has become an embedded resource and you will need to treat it differently. Obviously knowing how `TextIO` works would help

Comment: try putting the text file in src/test/resources/icecream.txt (or main instead of test) and passing "src/test/resources/icecream.txt" to readFile. Or put the text file one level above src.